JQ extract parent folder
I have an s3 route and I have to split it in bucket, prefix and key using JQ.
"s3://bucket/folder1/folder2/folder3/key.txt" ->

{
  bucket: bucket,
  prefix: folder1/folder2/folder3,
  key: key.txt
}


Quick / manual solution:
If you split on both // and / you can use $foo[0] to get the bucket, use $foo[-1] for the key (last index) and join the rest (1:-1) to get the prefix.
split("//")[1] | split("/") | {
    bucket: .[0],
    prefix: .[-1],
    key: .[1:-1] | join("/")
}

Demo

I think an S3 key could contain the character sequence // and still be valid, which might break this. E.g. I think you could haves3://bucket/strange//prefix/key.txt and then the split("//")[1] is going to discard everything on the right too.

Using regex capturing should do the trick while addressing any concerns regarding the use of split; e.g. with your input
capture("^[^:]*://(?<bucket>[^/]+)/(?<prefix>.*)/(?<key>[^/]+)$")

produces valid JSON:
{
  "bucket": "bucket",
  "prefix": "folder1/folder2/folder3",
  "key": "key.txt"
}

